# how to make `C-l` override `centered-cursor-mode`?

Tags: scrolling, centering

I love [centered-cursor-mode](https://melpa.org/#/centered-cursor-mode). It keeps my cursor in the center of the screen always.

However, on rare occasions, I need to use `C-l` `recenter-top-bottom` to "scroll" in order to view text lower than the center position allows.

In the meantime, I am forced to disable `centered-cursor-mode` and than use `recenter-top-bottom`, but I'd really prefer if there was a way to make `C-l` override  `centered-cursor-mode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just customize option `ccm-ignored-commands`, adding `recenter-top-bottom` to the list of commands that `centered-cursor-mode` lets happen without kicking in afterward.

---

How I found this:

I never heard of `centered-cursor-mode`. I followed your link, downloaded the source file, and looked through its options, to start with. Saw this option, tried it.